# Location of auth:api Middleware

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

Can somebody please tell the location of `auth:api` middleware?

As per the `auth:api` middleware, the api routes are protected by not null users.

I have a `boolean` field in user table called Is_Admin_Url_Accessible. I want to add a condition in the `auth:api` middleware for some routes to make user that only those user access such routes whoever are permitted to access the admin area.

I checked the class here but could not help.

```
\app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to edit vendor files. If you provide some more information, maybe you get a solution which fits better! 
Please share your routes (it seems that you want to treat some routes in a different way than others). 
And tell us the purpose of this boolean (do you want to turn the middleware off for these routes or...).

Comment: can u tell the location of which vendor file need modification?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add a middleware that makes control user accessible, and you can set it as middleware to your route group like `auth:api`

Please run `php artisan make:middleware UserAccessible` on your terminal.

After run above artisan command, you will see generated a file named `UserAccessible.php` in the `App/Http/Middleware` folder.

`UserAccessible.php` Contents

```php
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

    class UserAccessible
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $user = Auth::user();

            if(!$user->accesible){
                // redirect page or error.
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```

Then, you must define a route middleware via `App/Http/Kernel.php`

`Kernel.php` Contents

```php
    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'user_accessible' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserAccessible::class
    ];
```

And finally, you can define route middleware to your route group;

`api.php` Contents

```php
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api', 'user_accessible']], function () {
        // your protected routes.
    });
```

I hope this solve your problem.